# Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. try! get data(). Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, image, parse-platform, try-catch

I know that the error comes from `try! converyPFFile.getData()`

Wondering how to get rid of the error if I don't want to get data in background because if I get data in background, the image cannot be appended to the array. Thanks.

```
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            for object in objects! {
                self.senderArray.append(object.objectForKey("sender") as! String)
                self.messageArray.append(object.objectForKey("message") as? String)
                if object.objectForKey("photo") != nil {
                    if let converyPFFile = object.objectForKey("photo") as? PFFile{
                        let temp = try! converyPFFile.getData()
                        let image = UIImage(data: temp)
                        self.photoArray.append(image)
                    }
                } else {
                    self.photoArray.append(nil)
                }
            }
            // create a chat interface
            if self.senderArray[i] == self.userName {
                if self.messageArray[i] != nil {
                    // using scroll view
                    // create username label
                    // create message text label
                } else { 
                    // using scroll view
                    // create username label
                    // create message image
                    messageImage.image = self.photoArray[i]
                }
                ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this warning is coming from Parse. You can overcome it by using `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` and then append to your array within that block. Therefore your code becomes something like (untested and I think I have mis-paired braces):

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects! {
            self.senderArray.append(object.objectForKey("sender") as! String)
            self.messageArray.append(object.objectForKey("message") as? String)
            if object.objectForKey("photo") != nil {
                if let converyPFFile = object.objectForKey("photo") as? PFFile{
                    converyPFFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    self.photoArray.append(image)
                }
            } else {
                self.photoArray.append(nil)
            }
        }
        // create a chat interface
        if self.senderArray[i] == self.userName {
            if self.messageArray[i] != nil {
                // create username label
                // create message text label
            } else { 
                // create username label
                // create message image
                messageImage.image = self.photoArray[i]
            }
            ....
```

Comment: If I do it in background, image cannot be shown if I create the message image below.

Comment: I assume you're showing the image in a UITableView (or UICollectionView)? You just need to call `tableView.reloadData()` on the main thread after you've added the image to the array.

Comment: I do it in positioning the label and image in scroll view.

Comment: So you need to reset `messageImage.image` after the getData. You're already running on a background thread with `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, so you have to deal with the async load anyway. Also, why aren't you using a UICollectionView? From the code you've posted it looks like you're trying to achieve the same effect using a UIScrollView.

Comment: findobjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is not a problem as I also create the chat interface inside it. The reason why I am not using the table view or collection view is because I want to try a new way to do the same thing as I am a beginner in Xcode. So, based on my code, how can I use the async load?

Comment: What I'm saying is you show an empty image, and when the getData is finished, then you load it. You could "connect" the two by using the array index as the UIImageView's tag. When the load finishes, you find the image with that tag and display the data just loaded. If it's a chat interface it sounds like you should be using UITableView instead. Long chats will cause memory issues with your current code that UITableView solves for you. Don't try and reinvent the wheel, particularly as a beginner.

Comment: I got what you mean. I use your method. Inside the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock, I create if photoArray.count == objects.count {createChat()}, and it works. I am thinking to store the array locally, do you think that is a good way?

Comment: Yes, keeping a local array is a common way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute your task in the background while still making sure that appending to your photo array is done on the main thread.
You simply need to dispatch that particular code to the main thread.
See example below:

```swift
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects! {
            self.senderArray.append(object.objectForKey("sender") as! String)
            self.messageArray.append(object.objectForKey("message") as? String)
            if object.objectForKey("photo") != nil {
                if let converyPFFile = object.objectForKey("photo") as? PFFile{
                    let temp = try! converyPFFile.getData()
                    let image = UIImage(data: temp)
                    // this will cause self.photoArray.append to be executed on the main thread
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        self.photoArray.append(image)
                    })
                }
            } else {
                // this will cause self.photoArray.append to be executed on the main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.photoArray.append(nil)
                })
            }
        }
        // create a chat interface
        if self.senderArray[i] == self.userName {
            if self.messageArray[i] != nil {
                // create username label
                // create message text label
            } else {
                // create username label
                // create message image
                messageImage.image = self.photoArray[i]
    }
```

Comment: If I append my photo array on the main thread, I get this error "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Comment: It is probably because you are using self.photoArray somewhere else in the same method. This typically happens when you are looping on its content (for photo in self.photoArray ...) in one thread and adding or removing items in the array at the same time on another thread. If that is the case then you either need to work on a copy of self.photoArray while you are modifying photoArray, or you have to synchronize your code with semaphores of dispatch_groups to make sure all your code that edits self.photoArrays has completed before you start using self.photoArray in another thread.